# How do I add a class to each expanded form widget in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

Here are the Twig fields I'm trying to override: [github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig)

I have a list of checkbox that has been modified with this custom form theme:

```
{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {% for child in form %}
        <div class="checkbox_row">
        {{ form_widget(child) }}
        {{ form_label(child) }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

I tried adding a class using `{{ form_row(form.fieldName), {'attr':{'class':'myclass'}}) }}`

But that only adds a class to the `div#formName_fieldName`. Next I tried adding a custom block with

```
{% block _formName_fieldName_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} value="{{ value }}"  class="myclass_{{ value }}" />

{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

Notice I also included the value as I want to have `myclass_1, myclass_2` etc.

The problem with this is that the block receives an array so it should be like this

```
{% block _fb_post_facebook_pages_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {% for child in form %}
        {{ form_widget(child) }}
        {{ form_label(child) }}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

But then if I wanted to add the class to a specific checkbox, I would need to write something like this:

```
{% block _formName_fieldName_X_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} value="{{ value }}"  class="myclass_{{ value }}" />

{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

Where X would be a value that I have for the fieldName... And obviously the values could be anything so I can't just create block for all values from 1-1000000000000...

Any way to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to extend Twig, I believe. You can then specify the code in PHP and just bring in the conditions.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html